# Rerun Rsync After Unsuccessful Connection in Cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rsync

I have a bash script in my `cron` that has a passwordless `rsync` command to pass files from my local system to a web server.

**Bash Script Code:**

```
rsync -avzhe "ssh -p2222" ---chmod=Du=rw,Dg=r,Do=r,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r -p /home/sysadmin/some_file_{0..10}.png username@web.server:public_html/some.directory/
```

Over the past few days, I have noticed that the connection is randomly refused sometimes. I have correctly set up `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` and have set up the password `ssh` login successfully so, I'm not sure what is causing the connection to randomly be refused sometimes.

Now, I am looking for some code to force the `rsync` code to rerun until the files are successfully passed to the web.

**Rsync Code:**

```
RC=1 
while [[ $RC -ne 0 ]]
do
   rsync -avzhe "ssh -p2222" ---chmod=Du=rw,Dg=r,Do=r,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r -p /home/sysadmin/some_file_{0..10}.png username@web.server:public_html/some.directory/   
   RC=$?
done
```

Is this the best method to try and circumvent the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the return code of `rsync`, just do a loop like

```
#!/bin/bash

until rsync -avzhe "ssh -p2222" ---chmod=Du=rw,Dg=r,Do=r,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r -p /home/sysadmin/some_file_{0..10}.png username@web.server:public_html/some.directory/; do
  sleep 5              # waiting for 5 seconds before re-starting the command.
done
```